# changing margins on overleaf

Tags: margins, geometry

[image]How

I want to make these all four margins small. Now, these are two long, and text is too inside the page. How can I correct this ?

Comment: (a) If you are basing this off of a template given to you, then you shouldn't change it (b) If you are just trying to create something matching a formatting requirement, look into the 'geometry' package.

Comment: Yes, I try to create something matching a formatting requirement. What is he 'geometry' package ? Can you please write its command ? Thank you @WillieWong

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry (you should follow the link, and read the documentation to see how to use it).